# How to configure LumberJack(LogStash-forwarder) on windows

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-forwarder

I've installed ELK on my ubuntu server using this [manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04),

Now i want to index some log files from a windows server so I installed a logstash forwarder (LumberJack), but I can't get it to run.
this is the logstash-forwarder.conf file :

```
{
    "network": {
    "servers": [ "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:5000" ],
    "ssl key": "D:/lumberjack/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "ssl ca": "D:/lumberjack/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "timeout": 15,
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
         #single paths are fine
         "D:/bea12/Oracle/Middleware/domains/Google/servers/RT1/logs/AppLogs/RT1_APP_9_0.log",
         #globs are fine too, they will be periodically evaluated
         #to see if any new files match the wildcard.
        "/var/logauth.log"
      ],
  ]
    }
}
```

and this is the Error I get when i'm trying to run the **"lumberjack.exe"** ,
That I created with go-build:

```
2015/04/30 18:17:39.052033 Failed unmarshalling json: invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
2015/04/30 18:17:39.052033 Could not load config file d:\lumberjack\logstash-forwarder.conf: invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
By the way this is the command I'm using to run the forwarder:

```
lumberjack.exe -config="d:\lumberjack\logstash-forwarder.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
So the problem was in the configuration file, There were 2 unnecesary commas and no need for the **http:\**  at the start:

```
{
    "network": {
    "servers": [ "XX.XX.XX.XX:5000" ],
    "ssl key": "D:/lumberjack/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.key",
    "ssl ca": "D:/lumberjack/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "timeout": 15
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
         #single paths are fine
         "D:/bea12/Oracle/Middleware/domains/google/servers/RT1/logs/AppLogs/RT1_APP_9_0.log",
         #globs are fine too, they will be periodically evaluated
         #to see if any new files match the wildcard.
        "/var/logauth.log"
      ]
      }
  ]

}
```

This is my suggested configuration file for **LumberJack** on windows.